# Capture scrapy spider status (Success and failure)

Tags: python, scrapy, decorator, scrapy-pipeline

I just started using scrapy. Now I am trying to migrate some of the old crawlers (simple python requests) to scrapy.

One thing I am struggling with is figuring out a way to capture the status of scrappy spider. In the old crawl script, I have a decorator called **task** that would decorates the script start function. The code snippet is like this:

```
@task(task_name='tutorial',
      alert_name='tutorial')
def start():
    raw_data = download_data()
    data = parse(raw_data)
    push_to_db(data)

if if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

So this task decorator would send a success or failure message depending on the running status of the script.

Now I want to use this decorator for scrapy spider. I am struggling to **find the right place to put this decorator** so that it would capture the running status of the spider from **request download** all the way to **pipeline**.

I use this command to start the spider:

```
scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Comment: as for me your decorator is useless in `scrapy` which is more complex then your `start()` function. `scrapy` is used to scrape many pages - some of them can give success other failure so which result should give decorator if you get two different statuses? As I know `scrapy` skip requests which failed and it only sends information to `log`.

Comment: You could save information about success at the end of `parse()`. You can use [errback](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing) in `Request` to call function when request fails. But problem is when you scrape many pages and you get many statuses - which one to choose as finall result. Or maybe calculate percentage - i.e. 60% pages was succesfull ?

Comment: @furas Thank you for the reply. I have an alert system that would receive the statuses via the task decorator. I can send both statuses to the alert system. But the what I really want to do it not just capture the error from request and parse, but also capture the error in pipeline (e.g., failure to push data to database in pipeline)  Is there a central place that I can just capture the error no matter where it's coming from.

Comment: I don't know scrapy as much to say if there is one place (because it is very complex) but it uses `logging` to display errors and other informations - so maybe if you replace `logging` then you could catch it in own logging class. See Scrapy doc: [logging](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)

Comment: @furas I have over a 100 requests (API call, web scrapping) per day. But every one of them is just one request. So it is not like I need a distributed system to do millions of requests per day. Now my workflow is 1. Make request 2. Parse the data 3. Push to the final destinations (can be sql databases, local file system or aws s3). The problem with this is there isn't much code re-use. I thought scrapy has very clearly-defined workflow. Apart from the paring bit which is data specific, I can pretty much re-use all the pipelines. Do you think scrapy is too heavy for this? Any recommendations?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your original question: [Capture scrapy spider running status using an already defined decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458037/capture-scrapy-spider-running-status-using-an-already-defined-decorator)